# multiple instances of html5 audioElement, can it be done with $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do i use use multiple instances of this on one page e.g a mysql while loop. if you imagine multiple instances of the below code, when you click 'play' it will play the first instance. but I need a code similar to these 3 lines :

```
$('.play').click(function () {
    $(this).audioElement.play();
});
```

but here is the working code.
(javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo "http://www.2click4.com/mods/wall/uploads/".$rowsound['
    file '].""; ?>');

    $('.play').click(function () {
        audioElement.play();
    });

    $('.pause').click(function () {
        audioElement.pause();
    });
});
```

(html)

```
<div class="play">Play</div>
<div class="pause">Stop</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course yes, but you need to get the native DOM element to call that function since jQuery doesn't have any idea about the native `play` method. This should probably work for you

**HTML**

```
<div class="play">
    <audio src="http://www.2click4.com/mods/wall/uploads/1709824424.wav"></audio>
    Play
</div>
<div class="pause">Stop</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.play').click(function () {
    $('audio', this).get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: this works! thanks for that, although i have noticed it lags, is there any reason for why the previous code didnt lag and this does?

Comment: @user3206729 I' not entirely sure why it lags, but I suspect it's because you are handling too much buffers, and it takes time. In that case nothing to do but to switch to [`Web Audio API`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/).  Any upvote or accept is much appreciated if this helped.

Comment: @user3206729 [web audio getting started guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)